# How to draw two vertical lines using DrawingBrush and plying on Viewbox and Viewport?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, toolbar, drawingbrush

i want to set the style of toolbar, i need to change the mover gripper looks like two pars 'vertically' the default style used the `DrawingBrush` to render the dashed lines, and i want to draw two lines without dashing, please show me How to draw two lines vertical using DrawingBrush and plying on Viewbox and Viewport?.

here is the xaml code snippet:

```
 <Rectangle Margin="0,2">
     <Rectangle.Fill>
              <DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,4,4"
                            ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                            Viewbox="0,0,8,8"
                            ViewboxUnits="Absolute"
                            TileMode="Tile">
               <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                     <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="#AAA"
                                             Geometry="M 4 4 L 4 8 L 8 8 L 8 4 z" />
                     </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
               </DrawingBrush>
     </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I retracted my close vote now.

Comment: That seems like more than necessary, isn't that thing just a a thumb style template? I'd think you could just go take the `StrokeDashArray` out of it and have what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `Path` element instead:

```
<Path Margin="0,2" Brush="#AAA" Data="M 4 4 L 4 8 L 8 8 L 8 4 z" />
```